# Can 'append after command' draw on top of a node, instead of underneath it?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make a node style in which some extra decorations will be drawn on top of the node. However, I'm having trouble getting them to be drawn *on top* of the node rather than behind it, as the following MWE demonstrates. Is there a way to achieve this?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
    simple node/.style = {%
        rectangle, draw%
    },
    barred node/.style = {%
        simple node,% 
        append after command = {%
            ([xshift=-1mm]\tikzlastnode.north east)%
            --%
            ([xshift=-1mm]\tikzlastnode.south east)%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % draw the extra path manually - works fine:
    \node[simple node, fill=yellow] at (0,0) (a) {A\,};
    \draw ([xshift=-1mm]a.north east) --([xshift=-1mm]a.south east);

    % without the fill this looks fine. (Note that "\draw node" is necessary, rather than just "\node".)
    \draw node [barred node] at (1,0) (b) {B\,};

    % but with the fill it breaks - the line is drawn behind the node instead of in front of it.
    \draw node [barred node, fill=yellow] at (2,0) (c) {C\,};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried using the not very well documented `execute at end node` key instead of `append after command`, but it complained that `\tikzlastnode` was undefined, so I guess I really need to use `append after command` to get that.

I also tried drawing the decoration inside a `\pgfextra` command, but that didn't help - it still ended up drawn underneath the node instead of on top of it. I guess in principle I could use `\pgfextra` in combination with layers to manoeuvre the decoration on top of the node, but that's pretty inconvenient and I'm hoping there's a better way. Ideally the decoration would be on the same layer as the node, just drawn after it.

Comment: The append after command will be drawn as part of the path and is not linked to anything of the node (line width, line styles, etc). Every path has three layers: behind, the path itself and before. The path itself is always on its layer. Everything else (nodes, pics and *edges*) will be either [`behind path`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/behind:path) or `in front of path` (the default). So, you could use an edge (which comes after the node so it would be on top of the node anyway unless you put it behind path while the node is in front).

Comment: How dynamic is your additional drawing? It might be worth to declare your own shape (based on `rectangle`) or sneak extra drawing in, maybe.

Answer (score 4):

A `path picture` option will survay to filling the node

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
    simple node/.style = {%
        rectangle, draw%
    },
    barred node/.style = {%
        simple node,% 
        path picture = {\draw ([xshift=-1mm]path picture bounding box.north east) --([xshift=-1mm]path picture bounding box.south east);}
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % draw the extra path manually - works fine:
    \node[simple node, fill=yellow] at (0,0) (a) {A\,};
    \draw ([xshift=-1mm]a.north east) --([xshift=-1mm]a.south east);

    % without the fill this looks fine. (Note that "\draw node" is necessary, rather than just "\node".)
    \draw node [barred node] at (1,0) (b) {B\,};

    % but with the fill it breaks - the line is drawn behind the node instead of in front of it.
    \draw node [barred node, fill=yellow] at (2,0) (c) {C\,};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems pretty perfect for my application, because (so far at least) I want all my decorations to be clipped by the boundary of the node. I'll leave the question open for a while though, in case there are other solutions as well.

Answer (score 3):

Every path actually provides three layers:

1. [`behind path`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/behind:path),
2. the path itself and
3. [`in front of path`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/in:front:of:path).

By default, all nodes, pics and edges that are specified on a path will be placed `in front of path`. (Coordinates as well but since they have no visual output they can be ignored.)

But what about `\node`s that aren't placed on a path? Well, they still are, because `\node` is just a shortcut for `\path node`.

If you use `append after command` its content is just added after the node on the normal path and is otherwise totally independent of the node and its styles (linewidth, line colors, filling, etc).

This is also the reason why you need `\draw node` or, more precise, `\path [draw] node`. (`\draw` is also just a shortcut for `\path [draw]`).
Indeed, you could have done

```
\node [barred node] at (1,0) (b) {B\,} [draw];
```

---

The `edge` operation can help with both problems: Firstly, just like a node, it will be put `in front of path` by default (and since it will come after the node it will also be on top of the node) and you have full control over its appearence. The default setting of `every edge/.style = draw` already is enough to let the line show up without having to use `\draw` or `[draw]` on the path the node is specified on.

For complex diagrams, it would be wise to specify the usual defaults like `draw = black, line to, solid, line cap = rect`.

--

The red node shows that transformations of the nodes (including scaling) will not properly apply to the extra line (solutions for this exist though).
Furthermore, line styles won't be inherited at all.

As an option, I've added a `barred node*` style that adds the drawing as part of the background path (that's the one that's always part of a shape and will inherit the settings of the node).

Since it will not be clipped against the rectangle I'm subtracting the outer seps so that the line will start in the middle of the line of the rectangle.

Using `rounded corners` with a radius bigger than 1mm will also not look good.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@addshape@anchor{\def\anchor##1{\pgf@sh@reanchor{\pgf@sm@shape@name}{##1}}}
\tikzset{
  add to bg path/.code=%
    \tikz@addoption{%
      \toks0\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname pgf@sh@bg@\tikz@shape\endcsname}%
      \toks1{\begingroup\tikz@addshape@anchor#1\endgroup}%
      \expandafter\edef\csname pgf@sh@bg@\tikz@shape\endcsname{\the\toks0 \the\toks1 }}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  simple node/.style = {rectangle, draw},
  barred node/.style = {
    simple node,
    append after command = {
        ([xshift=-1mm]\tikzlastnode.north east)
        edge
        ([xshift=-1mm]\tikzlastnode.south east)}},
  barred node*/.style={
    simple node,
    add to bg path={%
      \pgfpathmoveto{%
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{-1mm-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}
                              {-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}
                    {\northeast}}% or \anchor{north east}
      \pgfpathlineto{%
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{-1mm-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}
                              {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}
                    {\anchor{south east}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[simple node, fill=yellow]                           at (0,    0) (a) {A\,};
\draw ([xshift=-1mm]a.north east) --([xshift=-1mm]a.south east);
\node [barred node]                                       at (1,    0) (b) {B\,};
\node [barred node, fill=yellow]                          at (2,    0) (c) {C\,};
\tikzset{
  nodes = {dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 2.5\pgflinewidth, blue, rotate = 45}}
\node [barred node,  fill=red,   thick, line cap = round] at (0.5, -1) (d) {D\,};
\node [barred node*, fill=green, thick, line cap = round] at (1.5, -1) (e) {E\,};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]